# Firebase real time issue on dictionary object in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase to fetch the data real time. My structure of table as below.

```
"Bidding": {
    "-LwyoIpE-obs1244Zflz": {
        "Images": {
            "-LwyoIxdDbabEzKDNjz0": {
                "image": "bookings/15773068970yg5i.png",
                "imgae_key": "-LwyoIxdDbabEzKDNjz0"
            },
            "-LwyoIxei2rxOOrJAxhD": {
                "image": "bookings/1577306897vIXfc.png",
                "imgae_key": "-LwyoIxei2rxOOrJAxhD"
            }
        },
        "booking_id": "1128",
        "category_id": "4",
        "consumer_id": "143",
        "consumer_image": "/uploads/1576824430.jpeg",
        "created_obj": "2019-12-25 20:48:17",
        "date_time": "2019-12-26 01:47:34",
        "description": "Good",
        "email": "dev@consumer.com",
        "job_type": "1",
        "lat": "37.785834",
        "lng": "-122.406417",
        "order_refrence": "GATK-S-2127",
        "record_id": "-LwyoIpE-obs1244Zflz",
        "sub_category_id": "22",
        "tile": "Contracting works - polish​"
    },
}
```

On view load I have successfully getting "Images" data. I call the Firebase node and get image data.

```
Database.database().reference().child("Bidding").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
       let values = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
       let profile = values["consumer_image"] as? String ?? ""
       let images = values["Images"] as? Dictionary<String, Any>
       print(messages)
    }
})
```

But issue is when new child added in node images getting nil in real time. When I reload view controller images getting fine. Kindly help.

Comment: Your observer is on the *Bidding* node. Meaning that when a new node is added directly under *Bidding* as in */Bidding/some_new_node*, your firebase observe event will fire. However, if you add child nodes under *Bidding/auto_id/Images*, that event will NOT Fire as that's not the node being observed. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: yes. How can i observer Images node when new child added in firebase.

Comment: Add a new child.... Child of the *Bidding* node? Or child of the *Images* node within  each users node?

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem only happens when you're adding new data from your code (and not when you reload), I suspect that you're adding the new node with multiple calls to `setValue(...)` or `updateChildValues(...)`. For example with:

```
let newChildRef = ref.child("Bidding").childByAutoId()
newChildRef.child("booking_id").setValue("1128")
newChildRef.child("consumer_image").setValue("/uploads/1576824430.jpeg")
```

In the above code, the first `setValue` call will trigger your `.childAdded` listener. And since at that point you haven't written a value for the `consumer_image` property yet, the value of `profile` in your listener will be `nill`.

The second call to `setValue` instead triggers a `.childChanged` event, which you're not listening for.

You have two options to fix the problem:

1. Write all properties for the node in a single write operation.
2. Listen to updates to the node.

---

#### Write all properties for the node in a single write operation

To prevent the `.childAdded` from triggering when you've only written partial data for the node, you'll want to make sure to write all data in one call to `setValue()` or `updateChildValues()`. The documentation on [updating specific property values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data) shows a good example of this. For the code snippet above, that would translate to:

```
let values = ["booking_id": "1128",
            "consumer_image": "/uploads/1576824430.jpeg"]

ref.child("Bidding").childByAutoId().setValue(values)
```

Since there now is only one call to `setValues`, your `.childAdded` listener will be triggered with all the values you passed in that (first/only) call.

---

#### Listen to updates to the node

An alternative to the above solution would be to *also* listen for updates to the node with a `.childChanged` listener. In that scenario your listeners will have to handle that some properties may not exist yet.

Something like:

```
Database.database().reference().child("Bidding").observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
   let values = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]

   if let profile = values["consumer_image"] {
     print(profile)
   }
})
```

Comment: Actually I want to retrieve Images data when new child added. How can I get that Images node?

Comment: In your current data structure that means you'll need to listen to both `childAdded` and `childChanged` events. There is no way in your current structure to only listen to image changes.